# How to set Queue leght/Size in Masstransit for Rabbit MQ

Tags: rabbitmq, masstransit

I have generic code to use RabbitMQ through Masstransit. Now I want to set RabbitMQ's Queue Size/length.  But I can not figure out to set RabbitMQ's Queue/  size via Masstransit Code.

```
cfg.ReceiveEndpoint(config.QueueName, ec =>
            {
                var ctx = context.Resolve<IComponentContext>();
                foreach (var eventDtoType in eventTypes)
                {

     var appHandlerType = typeof(RabbitContextMessageToDtoAdapter<>).MakeGenericType(eventDtoType);

                    ec.Consumer(appHandlerType , type =>
                    {

                        try
                        {
                            return ctx.Resolve(adapterType);
                        }
                        catch (Exception e)
                        {

                            throw;
                        }

                    });
                }
            });
```

Comment: There is no size/length configuration on RabbitMQ. You can, however, set things like PrefetchCount if you use the `.ReceiveEndpoint(host, "queue-name", cfg =>...)` signature.

Comment: I can not use that overload method as host not available  so  I have to use cfg.ReceiveEndpoint(config.QueueName, ec =>...)